# HTML anchor not loading the right page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a very weird unexpected behavior.

I have and anchor tag that leads to a page in the same directory

```
<header data-role="header">
    <h1 class="storeName"></h1>
    <a href="admin.html">Admin Panel</a>
</header>
```

When I click on the anchor, that's a button, it loads the admin.html page, but not properly.

The page itself looks fine, but the in the `head` I **should** have `<script src="_js/myAdminScript.js"></script>` , but instead I have `<script src="_js/myScript.js"></script>` which is the part of the index.html .

The other problem comes when I try to make a button click work on the admin.html. 
I have jQuery code that does this `window.location.href = "admin.html#adminPage2";` but when I click the button, the page that is loaded as `index.html#adminPage2` ... The weird thing is that that jquery piece of code is only found in `myAdminScript.js` . If I access the admin.html page directly, not through a hyperlink, then everything works fine.

Edit:  Code that responds to the click on the admin.html. Note that this isn't the first version of code, I've tried using different events and got different results, but the main idea is that the redirection follows the relative path from index.html instead of the admin.html, which this code belongs to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adminValidate").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        if($("#adminLogin").val() == "admin" && $("#adminPass").val()=="admin"){
            window.location.href = "admin.html#adminPage2";
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid username and/or password!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post more code? It's hard to debug based on what you've given.

Comment: Are you clearing your browser's cache at all? If not, you could be working with an older version of the page.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein  did just cleared my browser and it's still happening.

Comment: @jktin12 Jquery that should do the link transfer, it responds to a button click in a form. 
`$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#adminValidate").submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
  if($("#adminLogin").val() == "admin" && $("#adminPass").val()=="admin"){
   window.location.href = "admin.html#adminPage2";
  }
  else{
   alert("Invalid username and/or password!");
  }
 });

});`

Comment: @Stefan Don't add lots of code like that as a comment, edit your question to include it.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Added

Comment: @Stefan Are there multiple version of anything in nearby directories, or things with similar names that you could be accidentally referencing?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Only one version of the scripts and the .html Like I said, I do get to the page I'm supposed to when I redirect from the index.html, however, for some reason my `<head>` doesn't load from that page, instead it's the same as index.html one. Once I refresh, that's when the page properly loads

Comment: I had a similar problem and at the end what I did was load the document in a `<div id=mainContent></div>`and using [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) scroll the div to the anchor...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Did you have to put the entire page in the same file and just separate using the regular jquery `<div data-role='page>'` ? Becuase I was redirecting to the separate html file.

Comment: @Stefan I was creating a one page application, so all pages get loaded into that div... I took the id of the anchors, get its `[$("#anchor).position().top](https://api.jquery.com/position/)` and then [scroll the div](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)... also doing it single page allow me to keep consistent the main script over all my "pages" and "share data" like the anchore call. Also I did it like that because the anchores wouldn't work the second time, when you try to clickl one it just did nothing...

Comment: @Stefan the loading of the pages occur clicking each menu button...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL You know this actually worked, I was hoping that my way would help avoid code clutter, but looks like I'll have to take your advice . Thanks!